# Combining two tables using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

i have two linq - sql queries, and im wondering how to join them..

First Query

```
 var ab = from a in Items_worker.getCEAItems()
                where a.ProjectCode == lbl_projectCode.Text
                select new
                {
                    a.ID
                };
```

Second Query

```
 var j = from c in tblInc_worker.get(c => c.MarginID == MarginID && c.IncTypeID == "CAPEX")
                orderby c.DateCreated
                select c.ID;
```

First Query would return:

fasf-1212-1212-1212-1212

afaa-1414-1414-1414-1414

Second Query would return:

fasf-1212-1212-1212-1212

afaa-1414-1414-1414-1414

0000-0000-0000-0000-0000

1111-1111-1111-1111-1111

question is how can i possibly join the two table. Wherein the second query should return all of the records with the same ID found in the first query plus the id containing "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000" second query..

The result should be:

fasf-1212-1212-1212-1212

afaa-1414-1414-1414-1414

0000-0000-0000-0000-0000

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to join the both queries, for example split your second query in two with conditions like :

```
var ab = from a in Items_worker.getCEAItems() 
            where a.ProjectCode == lbl_projectCode.Text 
            select new 
            { 
                a.ID 
            }; 


var j = from c in tblInc_worker.get(c => c.MarginID == MarginID && c.IncTypeID == "CAPEX") 
            orderby c.DateCreated 
            select c.ID where c.ID.Equals("0000-0000-0000-0000-0000"); 

var j1 = from c in tblInc_worker.get(c => c.MarginID == MarginID && c.IncTypeID == "CAPEX") 
            orderby c.DateCreated 
            select c.ID where !(c.ID.Equals("0000-0000-0000-0000-0000"));

var result = ab.Union(j.Union(j1));
```

Hope this helps..